# How can I speed $.offset() up?

Tags: jquery, performance, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a Backbone app with jQuery and Bootstrap.

On Firefox everything is ok, but i have some dramatically slow performances on some $.offset() calculation with Webkit browsers ($.offset takes about 250 milliseconds to perform)

Has anybody already experienced such behavior ?

Note : the dom elements $.offset is applied to are placed into a Bootstrap carousel and some nested collapse widgets (which use css3 transition property...)

Comment: Your question as it stands is quite open ended. Presumably you are looking for an answer to "How can I speed `$.offset()` up?". If so, please edit your question to reflect that. Additionally, it would be very useful to post a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new) that demonstrates your problem

Comment: please show your code, where is the html and js calling `$.offset`

Answer (score 2):

If possible, can you use pure JavaScript for that part? You can do so by using [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect):

```
element.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(element.top, element.right, element.bottom, element.left);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use native [offsetTop](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsettop.asp) and [offsetLeft](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsetleft.asp).

They're much faster and you can calculate right and bottom by adding width and height to left and top offsets.